# Mongomapper: Embedded document does not work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

I don't know what's going on but I can't seem to find working a very small piece of code. I used mongomappper without embedded documents and everything went fine. Using an embedded document I hit the brick wall. I'm following the instructions on the [mongomapper homepage](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/embedded-document.html) using the Rails console:

Here are my models:

```
class Assessment
  include Mongomapper::Document
  many :sections
end

class Section
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :title, String
  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

When I run:
`a = Assessment.create(:sections => [ Section.new(:title => 'test') ] )`

I will get the following output:

`=> #<Assessment _id: BSON::ObjectId('4e71efce69a74c0fb6000002'), sections: nil>`

I also tried with `a = Assessment.new()`, `a.sections << Section.new(:title => "test")`
but the same result.

Why is there nothing inside sections?

Comment: What version of Mongo?  What version of MongoMapper?  I think MongoMapper and Mongo 2.0 don't play well together yet. See: http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/8aab1abe6a0b348d?hl=en%3Fhl%3Den

Comment: I checked my versions and I was running mongodb 2.0.0, mongomapper 0.9.2, Rails 3.0.10, Ruby 1.9.2p290. 
I deinstalled mongo and installed version 1.8.3. I get the same error.

Comment: I think i just got confused with the way the data is displayed. mm 0.9.1 doesn't print `sections: nil` but 0.9.2 does even though there are sections inside...

Comment: Yah, probably a 0.9.2 thing that may have to do with http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/d0a29b8f2e73a2bb#msg_22120d718ea1a60c

Answer (score 1):

Including:

```
attr_accessible :sections
```

should make the create work (at it does for me). And you'll probably want to add:

```
validates_associated :sections
```

to make your Assessment validate the embedded Sections the way you'd probably expect.

Yeah, a couple years late but I just had to sort this problem out and Google brought me here.